# Year of intervention seems a better predictor than type of intervention (which is dependent on the year itself)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, multicollinearity, confounding

We have a small(n = 19) non-randomized pilot clinical study in which we compare two types of surgical procedures on various outcomes.

The choice of which procedure was to be performed depended completely from the year of intervention (pre/post 2008), with only 2 patients using the old procedure even if being operated on 2010 and 2014.

A simple regression analysis (log Gaussian link) showed high efficacy of the new intervention (OPA):

```
  Pred   Effect Size            CI  Statistic     Pval
1  OPA      RR: 1.29  [1.07, 1.56]       2.64  0.017 *
```

If we include the year of intervention though (as 5-year effect), this new parameter makes the intervention non-important:

```
  Pred   Effect Size            CI  Statistic     Pval
1  OPA      RR: 0.99  [0.81, 1.22]     -0.109 0.915 ns
2  5.years  RR: 1.28   [1.1, 1.47]       3.42 0.003 **
```

Now, we can presume that patient management, hospital procedures, operator skills, etc could have improved in the years, but it's hard to imagine such a clear effect on very precise surgical outcomes, while there are definite biological reasons on why the new intervention should improve the outcomes.

My impression is that, given the strong dependency between `year of intervention` and `type of surgery`, and given the higher degrees of freedom of `year` and being continuous, the last one takes up all the variance and therefore seems more significant.

So my question is: which of the following 3 situations is the more likely, given the background I gave (very bayesianish):

1. The `Year` could be actually more associated with the outcomes than the procedure (even if it doesn't make much sense) and this relationship should be investigated with more data.
2. The effect of `Year` is clearly a statistical artifact for the reasons I said before (ie. being continuous, having more degrees of freedom, etc).
3. Given this data, it's actually impossible to choose between 1 and 2.

Comment: In short: in such an small-sample non-randomized trial you can't tell apart year and type of surgical procedure. You could check what has changed with years and argue that the main change has been type of procedure, and this argument could be sound but it would not be an statistical argument.

Comment: @Pere: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - I did, but I think a deeper answer from somebody else is still likely.

Answer (score 4):

In short: in such an small-sample non-randomized trial you can't tell apart the effects of year and type of surgical procedure. You could check what has changed with years and argue that the main change has been type of procedure, and this argument could be sound but it would not be an statistical argument.

In general, it's difficult to infer causation just from observational data because predictors are usually correlated. In experimental settings, instead, we try to control for every relevant variable and predictors and make sure that predictors are independent.

Comment: Thanks Pere. yes with such a small sample it's hard to do causal inference. My question is more like: given the background I gave, which of the three situations is the more likely: 1. the year being more associated than the procedure is a real signal and should be investigated. 2. year is more strongly associated simply for the statistical reasons I hypothisized in my question (ie. being continuous, having more degrees of freedom, etc). 3. is actually impossible to choose between 1 and 2. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: I wouldn't say that there is an statistical reason (like being continuous) for year being more associated to the response. I would just say that there is no statistical way to tell apart year and procedure effect from your data. For a simple extreme example: if all I knew about farming were that white cows produce milk while black chicken don't, I couldn't tell if white cows produce milk because they are cows or because they are white. Basically, you only know that procedure 2 after 2008 works better than procedure 1 before 2008, and that's not different from the cows and chicken example.

Comment: yep, but you are comparing two correlated nominal variables. In this case the nominal one can be seen as a discretization of the continuous. So while the nominal one (procedure) tells you only that the mean of the outcome (continuos itself) could be different in the two groups, the continuos one (year) tells you how much difference given a number of years. There's definetly more information there and I wonder if the regression catches that.

Comment: Furthermore, I suspect that also the variability given by the two cases with the old procedure albeit having had surgery after 2008 could influence somehow.

Comment: Yes, my example was an absolutely extreme case. However, I'm afraid yours is bad enough, specially because your dataset is very small. With a very large sample, you can often tell apart effect of correlated variables.